# How could i use the same page with different content

Tags: android, arraylist, android-activity

I need to use the same page with different content for

Eg: `i have clicked Array[name] button it will show the couple of names in listview next when i will click the address array the same activity instead of name can we show the address!!`

i have searched i find some thing like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, CalledActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(key, value);
        startActivity(intent);
```

here they used sqlite database for getting the content.could anybody help me @Thanks

Comment: do you want to just change content or the displayed view (user-interface) ?

Comment: @MehulJoisar yes..change the content in ui

Comment: then you can easily change content by assigning new adapter as suggested by j2emanue.if you have any further doubts then please post the code so that we can guide you for the same.

Answer (score -1):

im not understanding why you cant update the data then call notifyDataSetChanged() to update your listview.

you probably have your adapter defined something like this:
     ArrayAdapter myadapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, theDataSource1);

and then 
    theDataSource1=ArrayNames

so when the address button is clicked try
    theDataSourcd1=ArrayAddresses

then myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

another way but its bad design is you could have another Adapter and then change the listview's adapter whenever the buttons are clicked they would toggle.

Comment: k.thanks let me try..which will be better to try another class or adapter

Comment: just change the data source on the adapter its more clean.

Comment: j2emanue i am getting different array catagory using same adapter how could i change could you please give any brief example